# Loop comma separated values in awk function

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk

I want to extract the values from value2 variable, but this function is not printing the values.

`value2=aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd`

```
awk -F '|' -v value1=".$1" -v value2="$2"  '
{
    print "value1: " value1
    print "value2: " value2
    
    for ( i in value2//./ )
    {
        print "looping: " i
    }
}
```

input value `value2=aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd`
expected output:

```
aaaa 
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

How would I print all values using awk?

Comment: Which values ? Show us input file/expected output

Comment: input value 'value2=aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd'
expected output : 
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd

Comment: **Not in comment**. Edit your post

Comment: There's no `|` in your input. Why setting `FS` to it?

Comment: It required for further processing of csv file as it depends on the value1 & value2

Comment: `for ( i in value2//./ )` is not valid awk syntax

Comment: `awk -v str="a,b,c,d" 'BEGIN { n=split(str,arr,/,/); for (i=1;i<=n; i++) printf "[%s]\n", arr[i] }'`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd' |
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS=',' OFS='\n'
> ```

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

Comment: I have no idea what this answer means. Would you mind editing it with some explanation?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel : `NF=NF` is, by and large, a shorthand for `{ $1 = $1; print }` — both of them converts all input column delimiters (`FS`, or `"field separators"`) into output delimiters (`OFS`), with one minor caveat being that the short hand notation bypasses zero length input rows while the latter prints those regardless, but I like `NF=NF` because it's perfectly safe to type it at the console window, unquoted. but the `=` there is essential - just typing `NF` would print out non empty rows without actually converting the delimiters